# Case insensitive replace end with multiple spaces python

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to remove the string "with Ur" from the sql.

```
stringval=" select field1, field2 from table1 where field3=' WITH ur ' and field4 = ' test ' with   Ur "
stringval=" select field1, field2 from table1 where field3=' WITH ur ' and field4 = ' test ' with   Ur "
stringval=" select field1, field2 from table1 where field3=' WITH ur ' and field4 = ' test ' with Ur "
stringval=" select field1, field2 from table1 where field3=' WITH ur ' and field4 = ' test ' with Ur "
```

expected result
select field1, field2 from table1 where field3=' WITH ur ' and field4 = ' test '

remove the string at end containing 'with ur' in any case and any white space between them

```
insensitive_remove  = re.compile(re.escape('with ur$'), re.IGNORECASE
insensitive_remove.sub("",val.strip())
```

it works but not right. Regex is something i am missing for whitespaces

Comment: Can't you remove everything after the last quote `'`?

Comment: The select statement could be anything in this example i gave ' it could even "select field1, field2 from table1 with ur" i wanted to removed with ur at the end with whitespaces and with case insenstive without impacting teh case of space of rest of the string

Comment: `\s` represents any white space. One or more of it would be `\s+`

Comment: insensitive_remove  = re.compile(re.escape('\s+with\s+ur\s+$'), re.IGNORECASE) >>> insensitive_remove.sub("",stringval.strip())
"select field1, field2 from table1 where field3=' WITH ur ' and field4 = ' test ' with   Ur"

Comment: It didnt work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `re.escape`, in fact, it escapes too much.
Try this instead:

```
insensitive_remove = re.compile('\s*with\s+ur\s*$', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you simply ask for the last ' character and then split the String?
This should work

```
stringval=" select field1, field2 from table1 where field3=' WITH ur ' and field4 = ' test ' with   Ur "

str2 = "'";

lastIndexOfStr2 = stringval.rindex(str2)
print stringval[:lastIndexOfStr2 + 1]
```

Comment: The select statement could be anything in this example i gave ' it could even "select field1, field2 from table1 with ur" i wanted to removed with ur at the end with whitespaces and with case insenstive without impacting the case of space of rest of the string